# How to get http tag text by id using lua

Tags: lua

There is a webpage parser, which takes a page contains several tags, in a certain structure, where divs are badly nested. I need to extract a certain div element, and copy it and all its content to a new html file.

Since I am new to lua, I may need basic clarification for things might seem simple.

Thanks,

Comment: If you can identify where the piece of interest starts and end, it may be simple. Please give us an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: <div><div id="aa"><div>data included</div>data included</div>data excluded</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ease of extraction of data is going to largely depend on the page itself. If the page uses the exact same tag information throughout its entirety, it'll be much more difficult to extract than it would if it has named tags.

If you're able to find a version of the page that returns json format, then you're that much better off. Here's a snippet of code on something I wrote to grab definitions from a webpage that did not have json format:

```
local actualword, definition = string.match(wayup,"<html.-<td class='word'>%c(.-)%c</td>.-<div class=\"definition\">(.-)</div>")
```

Essentially, this code searched down the page until it found the class "word", and took the word after it (%c is the pattern for control characters). It continued on to "definition" and captured that, as well.

As you can see, it's a bit convoluted, but I had the luck of having specifically named tags for what I wanted.

This is edited to fit your comment. As a side note that I should have mentioned before, if you're familiar with regular expressions, you can use its model to capture what you need. In this case, it's capturing the string in its totality:

```
local data = string.match(page, "(<div id=\"aa\"><div>.-</div>.-</div>)")
```

It's rarely the fault of the language, but rather the webpage itself, that makes it hard to data mine anything. Since webpages could literally have hundreds of lines of code, it's hard to pinpoint exactly what you want without coming across garbage information. It's why I prefer a simplified result such as json, since Lua has a json module that can encode/decode and you can get your precise information.

Comment: Thanks to you, regarding what exactly I am searching for and my comment example, lets say that I need this whole string: "<div id="aa"><div>data included</div>data included</div>" regardless of the tags inside, I need them all. From your answer I get that there is no reliable html or xml parser to depend on, which is very bad I think, especially when the system forces us to use something like lua! Thanks a lot, and please let me know what the match string should be to handle that requirement.

Comment: Edited my answer to fit your particular request. Hopefully it works well for you.